# How to embed external html and change css styles?

Tags: html, css

I have a local `/swagger-ui.html` that is served from a different package/library. I want modify the style, thus I thought about embedding it into my own `index.html` and adding some `css` style overrides to it:

index.html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="import" href="/swagger-ui.html">
</head>
```

styles.css (same folder):

```
.swagger-ui .scheme-container,
.swagger-ui .topbar {
    background-color: red !important;
    display: none !important;
}
```

Result: I'm not seeing any changes on the styles. Why?

Comment: What if you charge the html before the css ? Or can you use some jQuery / js to change the css of the element after the page is load ? And if it's some html, why not include in the page ?

Comment: May I know the reason of linking <link rel="import" href="/swagger-ui.html"> on head!

Comment: Read this: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/
It will explain everything regarding how to work with scripts and styles inside an imported HTML file.

Comment: @MickaëlLeger I have not control over the `swagger-ui.html` as it comes from an external library. Thus I cannot change it.

Comment: @nazifarashid there is no reason. I'm just trying to embed a relative html and add some custom styles. If you have a better solution, I'd be happy to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the following lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="import" href="/swagger-ui.html">
```

to:

```
<link rel="import" href="/swagger-ui.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: That did not change anything.